# Encog training error for resilient backprop over 100%

Tags: c#, machine-learning, neural-network, classification, encog

I have a data set that when loaded, normalized, and fed into a feed forward neural network, by default (without any training) gives me over 100% error. From 130%-150% depending probably on the random weights. I was of the impression that the error rate can be at most 100%? Am I wrong?

When I run the iterations, the error drops to just below 100%.

Also, when training the network (tanh activation function for hidden layers and output), I sometimes get the value of Result over the limit (-1, 1). Like for example, Ideal value is 1, Result is 5.53042334202304 (made up value, but you get the point). I'm pretty sure this is wrong? Why is this happening?

What is this mess, and why is it happening? Is my data somehow not normalizing properly? Am I choosing some wrong configuration? Any suggestion is welcome as I'm running out of ideas here.

I have also uploaded my whole project so you can see and test for yourself.

[My Project Data](http://offsource.net/test-data.zip)

I am using Encog Workbench 3.2.0 to do all these tests, although this may not be Encog-related, I just don't know if I'm doing some basic mistake or just configuring it wrong in Encog Workbench.

Comment: can you post your code to train this model?

Comment: i train it using the encog workbench 3.2.0, it's an interface for the encog machine learning library, so you can test stuff out before you do any coding. So i don't have any code sorry.

Answer (score 0):

First of all implement some kind of normalizing and scaling of your data. You can do normalization by yourself or with help of "Analyst Wizard". Notice, that [here](http://www.wikirating.org/wiki/Rating_Method_Artificial_Neuronal_Network_(ANN)) data is already normalized before analysis. Also I noticed that in neuralnetwork.eg which you attached the last layer is marked as "ActivationLinear" and it's output can be in some cases 5. Change it to "ActivationTANH" and will not be more then 1

Comment: I do normalization. Everything is normalized using the analyst wizard. The analyst file is in the uploaded files as well. I use it to convert the csv to the normalized binary version ready for input. So everything that is fed into the network is normalized from -1 to 1. The Activation Linear that you're seeing is for the input layer, i can't change that. I belive it is always like that and that it doesn't affect the actual network. Because if you look at the NN configuration a little further, you can see it's just tanh->tanh and no linear function applied anywhere in it.

Comment: I may have missed something, let me know if i'm wrong! I was hoping the linear activation you spotted was the error, but after further investigation i don't think it is as it can't be changed at all, and i believe it's there just for show? Not sure really...